# Overlapping data labels (MPAndroidChart)

Tags: java, android, graph, mpandroidchart

If I have a lot of values with close values, the data labels overlap. For example this sequence of 14's:

[image]

Is there a way to de-clutter this somehow or "hide" labels that contribute to the clutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(5) it will skip five label. automatic lab

Comment: What is the equivalent in v3.0.0 ?

Answer (score 5):

For version 3.x you can try `xAxis.setLabelCount(4)`, but in your case may be better is `xAxis.setGranularity(1f)`